# Need VB.NET Resource Files clarification

Tags: vb.net

In a VB project I can add a resource via the project properties resources tab, or I can right-click the project in the solution explorer, click add, then click add existing item.

What are the differences?

If I want to add a DLL file and include it as an embedded resource, do I have to add the file via both methods? Only one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is linked and embedded resources.

Check out this page which describes the differences:

[Linked vs. Embedded Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8%28VS.80%29.aspx)

From the MSDN link above:

**Embedded Resources**

Embedded resources are the best choice if you need to share application resource (.resx) files between multiple projects.

For example, if you have a common resource file that contains your company's logos, trademark information, and such, using embedded resources means you only have to copy the .resx file and not the associated resource data files.

You cannot edit embedded resources directly. If you try to edit an embedded resource, you will receive a message prompting you to convert the item to a linked resource in order to edit it; conversion is recommended but optional. You must export them, make your modifications in an external program, and then import them back into your project.

**Linked Resources**

Linked resources (the default) are the best choice for ease of use.

Resources can be edited directly inside the project, and you can easily add or remove resources as needed.

---

**Edit**

You would only need to add your DLL using one method. Which one you select depends on which method best fits your needs (as per the descriptions above)

Comment: The description above makes me think that if I embed a DLL in my project I will then have to ship the resx file with my application, and I know that is not the case. Right now I have an embedded DLL and when my application needs it I can "WriteAllBytes" from "My.Resources" and the embedded DLL is written to the harddrive without ever needing a resx file. So I am still confused.